# please explain this weird behaviour c++ multiplying numbers then mod

Tags: c++, type-conversion

i have less experience with c++ and i code mainly in python. while solving some programming challenge online there was a part of code where i have to multiply two numbers and reduced it with mod.

```
v = (u*node) % 100000
```

where u and node are int values with range 1 - 100000. Due to time limit issues i wrote my code in c++. Here what i wrote

```
long long v = (u * node) % 100000;
```

while submitting i got runtime error in all the test cases. I downloaded failed test cases and ran in my local computer and i was getting perfect output.

After seeing editorial, i change that line to something like this

```
long long v = u;
v = (v*node) % 100000;
```

and submitted. I passed all the test cases. Please can anyone explain whats the difference between those two lines..

variable data types -

```
int u
int node
```

Comment: multiplying an int with another int stays an int.

Comment: 100000*100000 overflows on 32 bit.

Answer (score 5):

Because `u` and `node` are both `int`s, this expression,

```
(u * node)
```

produces an `int` result. If it overflows—meaning that the result is too large to fit in an `int`—too bad. Signed integer overflow is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and all bets are off. Chances are, it'll do something like wrap around, but it could also format your hard disk.

When you make `u` a `long long int`, then the same expression produces a `long long int` result. The `node` multiplicand gets *implicitly promoted* to a `long long int` (`int` to `long long int` is a widening conversion, so it is always safe), and then these two `long long int` values get multiplied. This operation won't overflow, so you avoid undefined behavior and get the correct result.

You could have also written the code with an explicit cast to avoid the declaration of a new variable:

```
(static_cast<long long int>(u) * node)
```

Note that it doesn't matter *which* value you promote, the result will be the same because the other value will get implicitly promoted, as described above:

```
(u * static_cast<long long int>(node))
```

On the other hand, this won't work:

```
static_cast<long long int>(u * node)
```

because it only widens the *result* of the multiplication operation, *after* the multiplication has been performed. If that multiplication overflowed the `int` type, then it is already too late.

It is the same reason that this doesn't work—the promotion to `long long` happens *after* the result is evaluated as an `int`:

```
long long v = (u * node)
```

Comment: That's the great thing about undefined behavior: getting the "right" result is always a possibility. An alternative explanation is that your local computer is using a 64-bit compiler that makes `int` a 64-bit type, whereas the remote computer is using a 32-bit compiler that makes `int` a 32-bit type. If `int` is larger, it won't overflow. But you can't guarantee that `int` will be 64 bits, so you need to use a larger integer type to make sure it works everywhere. That's why you use `long long int`.

Comment: can you suggest me some books.

Comment: @Atul *but i get correct output in my local computer* -- Ever hear of programs working ok at the "shop", but fail when run on the customer's computer?  This is no different.

Answer (score 2):

> Please can anyone explain whats the difference between those two lines..

first line actually mean:

```
long long v = (long long) (int * int % int);
```

so, first you multiply int by int, **get overflow**, **truncate to int**, mod, extend int to long long

next line actual mean:

```
long long v = (long long) int;
v = long long * int % int;
```

so, first **extend int to long**, multiple long by int, **no overflow**, mod, assign to long long

Comment: i think u mean long long in most places u say long

Answer (score 0):

Probably you were running into an overflow in the first case (both u and v as ints). This happens because when multiplying variables, the compiler will keep the result in a temporary variable that has the same type of the highest type (int, floats, doubles, etc) of the variable in the multiplication. So, if you are multiplying two big integers, the result can overflow.

Your modification works because the temporary result is stored in a long long, which does not overflow in your examples.